# what to return from azure function that is async

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function that looks a bit like this:

```
module.exports = async (context: Context, req: any) => {
  const canProceed = await new Auth().verify(context, req);

  if (!canProceed) {
    context.res = {
      status: 401,
      body: 'Unauthorised'
    };

    return context.done(undefined, context);
  }

  context.res = doStuff();

  return context.done(undefined, context);
}
```

When I run the function locally I get this warning or error:

> Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'.  Do not use both in your script.

It is not clear from the docs how this should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#exporting-an-async-function).

> When using the async function declaration or plain JavaScript Promises in version 2.x of the Functions runtime, you do not need to explicitly call the `context.done` callback to signal that your function has completed. Your function completes when the exported async function/Promise completes.
>
> When exporting an async function, you can also configure an output binding to take the return value. This is recommended if you only have one output binding.

Change the `name` property to `$return` in `function.json` if it's not.

For http trigger,

```
{
  "type": "http",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "$return"
}
```

And your function code needs modification as well. Note that `doStuff()` is supposed to return a valid response as expected.

```
module.exports = async (context: Context, req: any) => {
  const canProceed = await new Auth().verify(context, req);

  if (!canProceed) {
    return {
      status: 401,
      body: 'Unauthorised'
    };
  }
  else return doStuff();

}
```